# Use jquery to update a dynamic hidden date field so that displayed field can show a user-friendly date

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datepicker, jquery-tools, hidden-field

I have a date input field in my form and the date format is YYYY-MM-DD but I want to hide that by dynamically creating another input field linked to that one with jquery-tools datepicker attached to the additional field.

This will mean the user will be presented with a normal looking input field which uses jquery-tools datepicker. When the user selects a date in the datepicker it displays it in the visual field as "Fri, 30 Mar 2012" but it also updates the actual [hidden] field with "2012-03-30".

I managed to get this to work using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.tools.dateinput.conf.format = 'ddd, d mmmm yyyy';

  $('.date-field').each(function(i, el) {
    var field = $(el);
    var dateParts = field.val().split('-');
    var d = new Date(parseInt(dateParts[0]), parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1, parseInt(dateParts[2]));
    var initDate = (isValidDate(d)) ? d : '';
    var dateField = $("<input type='text' class='injected-date-field'>").dateinput({ value: initDate} );

    $("#occurrences").delegate(".injected-date-field", "focusin", function(){
       $(this).dateinput();
    });

    // Without this, the field is initially blank
    if (initDate !== '') {
      dateField.val(dateField.data().dateinput.getValue($.tools.dateinput.conf.format));
    }

    dateField.bind('beforeChange', function(event, date) {
      // build date string, eg 2012-03-15
      year  = date.getFullYear().toString();
      month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
      if (month.length == 1) { month = '0' + month; }
      day   = date.getDate().toString();
      if (day.length == 1) { day = '0' + day; }

      field.val(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
    });
    field.before(dateField);
    field.hide();
  });

  function isValidDate(d) {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN(d.getTime()));
  }
});
```

My issue lies in the fact that these date input fields can be added dynamically by clicking a button to let the user add more occurrences to the form. The new field appears and it creates an injected-date-field which has jquery-tools datepicker attached to it....all's well so far....but the beforeChange on the injected-date-field doesn't attach to the newly created fields properly so when a date is selected from this datepicker it doesn't update the actual [hidden] field. This works for any that are loaded on page load but not for dynamically added ones.

Hope that all makes sense, sorry but I've not really got an example to show it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of possible approaches:

1. Use a named function

   - Within the `$(document).ready(...)` closure, split out the anonymous `$('.date-field').each()` function as a named function.
   - Whenever a new `.date-field` is added, call the named function to attach datepicker functionality, including hidden field handling.
2. Create a ptototype field/dateField

   - Create a container (typically a div or span) with `id="dateFieldPrototype"`.
   - Populate the container with a hidden `field` and its corresponding `dateField`. These can be hard-coded HTML or dynamically generated.
   - Hide the prototype.
   - Add dateInput functionality to the prototype `dateField`, including the 'beforeChange' handler.
   - Amend the 'beforeChange' handler to discover its hidden field rather than relying on a reference to it in the closure.
   - Generate all original and subsequently added datepickers by cloning the original.

   `$("#dateFieldPrototype").clone(true,true).appendTo(selector).show();`

With a bit of effort, either of these approaches can be made to work.

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 was very useful and I've now got it working. I've replaced the anon function with a named function which gets called for each on load and as well as whenever a new `.date-field` is added.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your `beforeChange` will get bounded to only existing DOM elements. It won't get bound to the elements added dynamically. To do that use [`.on('beforeChange', function(){})`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (Only jQuery 1.7+). If you are using an older version of jquery use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

Secondly there is a better way of creating hidden date fields. Check out [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field) from jQuery UI datepicker.